Getting maximum call stack for grunt
I am running grunt on my project as follows, I am new to grunt could some one please help me
ts% grunt copy-node-modules
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR


RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.


Aborted due to warnings.
Execution Time (2024-10-17 11:49:21 UTC)
loading tasks  30.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
Total 30.1s
my gruntfile.js,
nodeModulesDir: {
                files:[
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules', // source directory
                        src: [
                            'ng-file-upload/**/*.js', // add required npm moudles here
                            'angular-dynamic-locale/**/*',
                            'higcharts/**/*',
                            'highcharts-ng/**/*',
                            'respond.js/**/*',
                            'angular/**/*',
                        ],
                        dest: 'app/lib' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/froala-editor', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                         dest: 'app/lib/froala-wysiwyg-editor' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/@npm',
                        src: [                        
                            './angular-read-more/**/*'
                        ],
                        dest: 'app/lib'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/@npm',
                        src: [                        
                            './angular-event-delegate/**/*'
                        ],
                        dest: 'app/lib'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/angular-numeraljs/node_modules/numeral',
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/numeral'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/jquery-ui-sortable', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                         dest: 'app/lib/jquery-ui-sortable' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/lodash', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                         dest: 'app/lib/lodash' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/angular-md', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/angular-md' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/angular-scroll', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/angular-scroll' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/angular-touch', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/angular-touch' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/bootstrap', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/bootstrap' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/angular-ui-bootstrap' // target directory
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'node_modules/angular-ui-sortable', // source directory
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: 'app/lib/angular-ui-sortable' // target directory
                    },
                ]
            }

         grunt.registerTask('copy-node-modules', ['copy:nodeModulesDir']);


I am trying to run grunt copy-node-modules

Take a look at your gruntfile.js and compare it to the sample. What you have in there does not appear to be valid javascript code
